# Color harmonies:triada, complement, analogous, monochromatic

Tags: c#, .net, colors, color-scheme

I need help in color math. I have one main color and i need to get other colors of chosen harmony.
I need such color harmonies: triada, complement, analogous, monochromatic. I need them in C#.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Dima.

Comment: You might get more answers if you give us some definitions of the harmonies you need. That way answerers only need to know C#, not C# and color harmonies. :)

Comment: I thought i give you definitions color harmonies: triada, complement, analogous, monochromatic. Or i miss something?

Comment: @user604790. Those aren't definitions, that's just a list of different color harmonies. I meant for you to include an explanation of what triada is, what complement is, what analogous is and what monochromatic is.

Comment: here is a link where it is explained:http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, everything revolves around the color wheel described in your [link](http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm). I suggest hardcoding those colors in an array. I'm assuming your main color is always one of those 12.

One helper method we're going to need is one that will wrap values around the array, such that color -1 becomes color 12 (index 11 in the array):

```
int WrapColor(int colorIndex, int numWheelColors)
{
    while(colorIndex < 0)
    {
        colorIndex += numWheelColors;
    }

    colorIndex = colorIndex % numWheelColors;
}
```

We also need a helper method that will get the index of a color on the color wheel:

```
int GetColorWheelIndex(Color color)
{
    if (ColorWheelArray.Contains(color))
        return ColorWheelArray.IndexOf(color);
    else
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("color");
}
```

Now everything's in place (assuming you've got an array called ColorWheelArray, containing the colors **in order**).

Triada:

```
Color[] GetTriadaColors(Color color)
{
    int colorIndex = GetColorWheelIndex(color, ColorWheelArray.Length);
    return new Color[]
        {
            color,
            ColorWheelArray[WrapColor(colorIndex + ColorWheelArray.Length / 3)],
            ColorWheelArray[WrapColor(colorIndex + 2 * ColorWheelArray.Length / 3)]
        };
}
```

Compliment:

```
Color GetComplimentColor(Color color)
{
    int colorIndex = GetColorWheelIndex(color, ColorWheelArray.Length);
    return ColorWheelArray[WrapColor(colorIndex + ColorWheelArray.Length / 2)];
}
```

Analogous:

```
Color[] GetAnalogousColors(Color color)
{
    int colorIndex = GetColorWheelIndex(color, ColorWheelArray.Length);
    return new Color[] { color,
                         ColorWheelArray[WrapColor(colorIndex + 1)],
                         ColorWheelArray[WrapColor(colorIndex + 2)] };
}
```

As i don't know the definition of monochromatic i'll leave that to you. :)

---

EDIT: If you want it to work with any color then i'm not 100% sure, however i've got an idea.

That site says the wheel is created by picking colors in the RYB color space (not the RGB one that C# uses). So presumably you could work out how 'far' your color is to each of the colors on the wheel (by converting both to RYB and comparing), then use my functions to get the other color(s). Finally add on the difference between your color and the closest wheel color (in RYB color space) to each result, finally translating back into RGB to store as a Color object.

Comment: Thanks for help it is great. But need to find color harmony for every color that i give but not only for 12. Thanks

Comment: Then you'll need to give me more to go on. That page doesn't show how to do it for other colors. Also, see my edit bottom of answer.

Comment: I also dont know so i ask this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, well i think unless someone comes along who happens to know color theory you might have to go with my edit at the bottom of my answer. You could try asking the question on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com then if you can get a good explanation then someone here could help with the actual code.

Comment: Ok, i don't have time to do this one for you, but to do what you want you'll need to convert RGB color into CIELCH color space then do the transformed described in the url above then translate back to RGB. I couldn't find much info on translating from RGB to CIELCH and back, because RGB is device-dependant. I did find a link to an excel spreadsheet that does it using formulas, so you could look at that to work it out. Once this is done returning colors based on changing the CIELCH color should be easy. http://ccc.orgfree.com/